# Global Sessions?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to get the variable from one page on my site to another using sessions but failing.

Example from page 1:

```
session_start();

$_session['error'] = "1";
```

Example from page 2:

```
session_start();

if ($_session['error'] == "1") {
    print '<font color="#ff0000">You need to sign in with a username!</font>';
}
```

Comment: YOUR SESSION ARRAY IS NOT YELLING AT YOU.  WHY NOT!

Comment: You need to use upper case `$_SESSION` not `$_session`. These are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION` and `$_session` are two different variable one is basic variable and another is GLOBAL variable.

You need to the GLOBAL one. As you are using the variable in two different page so you have to go with the uppercase one that is `$_SESSION`. If you store at that variable you can access the variable from any page in the same domain with the help of `session_start`.

**Solution:**

*Page_1.php*

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['error'] = "1";
```

*page_2.php*

```
session_start();    
if ($_SESSION['error'] == "1") {
    print '<font color="#ff0000">You need to sign in with a username!</font>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$_SESSION['error']` instead of `$_session['error']`. `$_SESSION` stores information in the session whereas `$_session` is just a variable on the page because it's lowercase. Thus your pages become

Example from page 1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['error'] = "1";
```

Example from page 2:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['error'] == "1") {
    print '<font color="#ff0000">You need to sign in with a username!</font>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well.

As they say, you learn something new everyday.

Comment: @JamesGedny Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)